# Looking for a good Java IPV6 library for ranges calculation

Tags: java, networking, ipv6

I'm looking for a java library to handle IPV6 ranges calculation such is:
Does range A overlap range B?
Is range A contained in range B?
Does IP A included in range B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the range utilities in the Guava library:

## [RangeSet](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained)

## [Range](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained)

Check out the RangeSet, RangeMap and Range classes.
I believe that with the relevant IPv6 types it can provide the necessary functionality.
Since I didn't have the chance to do real testing yet if someone has some real experience it will be great to hear about it.